# How to pick the %f from this result?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code

```py
from obspy.taup import TauPyModel
model = TauPyModel(model="ak135")

arrivals = model.get_travel_times(source_depth_in_km=573.7, distance_in_degree=69.13, phase_list=["P","pP","PP"])
```

arrivals is result. So you see

print(arrivals)

3 arrivals

```
P phase arrival at 609.410 seconds

pP phase arrival at 725.852 seconds

PP phase arrival at 772.376 seconds
```

and It also can be showed one row.

print(arrivals[0])

P phase arrival at 609.410 seconds

I have to use the %f term (609.410). There are many data.
so, I want to pick the %f term to analyse. What Should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code uses re. The part \d+[?:.\d+] checks for both integer and floating point patterns.

```
import re
list_ = [re.findall('\d+[?:\.\d+]*',str(arrival))[0] for arrival in arrivals]
```

Answer (score -1):

You may iterate the arrivals and populate a new list of times:

```
times = list()
for arrival in arrivals:
    times.append(arrival.time)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I couldn't follow your code. Do I have to do any import module before using this code?? the error massages are 'expected str instance, Arrival found' at '' (previous .join), and "re" is not defined (previous .findall)

Comment: @정찬웅 Did you imported the `re` module before trying this?